# Applied logic challenge problem #2

Tags: logical-deduction, computer-puzzle

This is similar to my previous Applied Logic Challenge Problem but with a significant difference at the end which could make this problem somewhat more difficult. Again it is a problem of my own devising. You must determine what can be concluded from the 40 true statements below. The numbers in each statement represent binary values (true / false, 1 / 0), or attributes that either are present or are not present.  Do not confuse statement numbers (like Statement 9:) with the numbers within each statement which refer to the binary attributes (like 10,9,13 and 16 within Statement 9).  These attributes do not refer to statement numbers.

For example, in words, Statement 1 reads:
If 22 is true and 29 is true then 9 is false.
Statement 9 is unrelated to this and remains true (all the statements are true)

> statement 1 :  if 22 and 29 then not 9
>   statement 2 :  if 21 and 10 then 29
>   statement 3 :  if 20 and 32 and not 17 then 24
>   statement 4 :  if 20 and 19 and not 5 then 18
>   statement 5 :  if ( 9 and 16 ) or ( 20 and not 30 ) then 11
>   statement 6 :  if ( 28 and 15 ) or ( 23 and not 8 ) then 21
>   statement 7 :  if 7 or 35 then 3
>   statement 8 :  if 19 and 11 then not 25
>   statement 9 :  if 10 and 9 and not 13 then 16
>   statement 10 :  if 29 or 27 then 7
>   statement 11 :  if 34 or 1 then not 32
>   statement 12 :  if 25 or 32 then 27
>   statement 13 :  if 25 and 18 then not 22
>   statement 14 :  if 5 or 14 then not 24
>   statement 15 :  if 25 and 34 then not 29
>   statement 16 :  if 36 or 27 then not 34
>   statement 17 :  if 14 and 15 then not 13
>   statement 18 :  if 20 or 12 then not 30
>   statement 19 :  if 6 or 26 then 34
>   statement 20 :  if 14 and 11 and not 24 then 16
>   statement 21 :  if ( 5 and 7 ) or ( 14 and not 12 ) then 1
>   statement 22 :  if 15 or 9 then 2
>   statement 23 :  if 25 or 3 then 16
>   statement 24 :  if ( 32 and 18 ) or ( 27 and not 26 ) then 11
>   statement 25 :  if 22 and 9 and not 7 then 14
>   statement 26 :  if 9 or 13 then 6
>   statement 27 :  if 2 or 19 then 1
>   statement 28 :  if 25 and 12 then not 9
>   statement 29 :  if 21 or 11 then 27
>   statement 30 :  if ( 17 and 1 ) or ( 24 and not 36 ) then 22
>   statement 31 :  if 26 or 23 then 6
>   statement 32 :  if 2 or 28 then 23
>   statement 33 :  if 29 or 35 then 11
>   statement 34 :  if 20 or 10 then 18
>   statement 35 :  if 19 and 7 and not 10 then 1
>   statement 36 :  if ( 27 and 22 ) or ( 2 and not 34 ) then 6
>   statement 37 :  if 34 and 7 and not 4 then 29
>   statement 38 :  if 29 or 5 then not 12
>   statement 39 :  if 4 and 33 and not 1 then 14
>   statement 40 :  if 31 or 15 then 32

Comment: "*statement 9 : if 10 and 9 and not 13 then 16*" - That 9 means that they are self-referential?

Comment: @VictorStafusa, I made the same mistake in the previous puzzle. The statement numbers are unrelated to the numbers in the statement. Statement 9 is definitely true. Number 9 could be true or false.

Comment: Yes, Dr. Xorile is right.  Also, I added some further clarification in the problem description.  Another way to easily visualize this is to consider the numbers within each statement (not the statement number) as letters instead of numbers.  It just was much easier for me to generate this problem without using letters.

Comment: Bob, if it's easy for you (and if you intend to post another one) to just use letters right from the beginning. You can go A-Z, then keep going by using greek letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the answer is:

> 15 is always False. Any other number can go either way.

The reason is:

> if 15 is True then:
>  statement 22 : 15 or 09 implies 02
>  statement 27 : 02 or 19 implies 01
>  statement 11 : 34 or 01 implies not 32
>   and
>  statement 40 : 31 or 15 implies 32
>  Therefore, 15 is False

Apart from that:

> There exist examples of all the other ones going either way.

Here is a more general set of conclusions to help anyone looking for the other conclusion the OP is looking for. In each case, if you set one of the values to 1, then there are certain conclusions that you can draw. In this case, "_" means that you can't draw any particular conclusion about that specific variable.

```
If 01 is 1 then 1______________________________0____
If 02 is 1 then 11___1________________1________0_1__
If 03 is 1 then __1____________1____________________
If 04 is 1 then ___1________________________________
If 05 is 1 then ____1______0___________0____________
If 06 is 1 then _____1_________________________0_1__
If 07 is 1 then __1___1________1____________________
If 08 is 1 then _______1____________________________
If 09 is 1 then 11___1__1_____________1________0_1__
If 10 is 1 then _________1_______1__________________
If 11 is 1 then __1___1___1____1__________1______0__
If 12 is 1 then ___________1_________________0______
If 13 is 1 then _____1______1__________________0_1__
If 14 is 1 then _____________1_________0____________
If 15 is 1 then no stable solution found
If 16 is 1 then _______________1____________________
If 17 is 1 then ________________1___________________
If 18 is 1 then _________________1__________________
If 19 is 1 then 1_________________1____________0____
If 20 is 1 then __1___1___1____1_1_1______1__0___0__
If 21 is 1 then __1___1________1____1_____1______0__
If 22 is 1 then _____________________1______________
If 23 is 1 then _____1________________1________0_1__
If 24 is 1 then _______________________1____________
If 25 is 1 then __1___1________1________1_1______0__
If 26 is 1 then _____1___________________1_____0_1__
If 27 is 1 then __1___1________1__________1______0__
If 28 is 1 then _____1________________1____1___0_1__
If 29 is 1 then __1___1___10___1__________1_1____0__
If 30 is 1 then _____________________________1______
If 31 is 1 then __1___1________1__________1___11_0__
If 32 is 1 then __1___1________1__________1____1_0__
If 33 is 1 then ________________________________1___
If 34 is 1 then _______________________________0_1__
If 35 is 1 then __1___1___1____1__________1______01_
If 36 is 1 then _________________________________0_1
```

So a possible conclusion could be something like:

> 34 and 32 are not both true.

In fact, you can draw this kind of conclusion for a number of results:

> 1 and 31 are not both true
>  1 and 32 are not both true
>  2 and 11 are not both true
>  2 and 20 are not both true
>  2 and 21 are not both true
>  2 and 25 are not both true
>  2 and 27 are not both true
>  2 and 29 are not both true
>  2 and 31 are not both true
>  2 and 32 are not both true
>  2 and 35 are not both true
>  2 and 36 are not both true
>  3 and 9 are not both true
>  5 and 12 are not both true
>  5 and 24 are not both true
>  5 and 31 are not both true
>  5 and 32 are not both true
>  6 and 11 are not both true
>  6 and 20 are not both true
>  6 and 21 are not both true
>  6 and 25 are not both true
>  6 and 27 are not both true
>  6 and 29 are not both true
>  6 and 31 are not both true
>  6 and 32 are not both true
>  6 and 35 are not both true
>  6 and 36 are not both true
>  7 and 9 are not both true
>  9 and 11 are not both true
>  9 and 16 are not both true
>  9 and 20 are not both true
>  9 and 21 are not both true
>  9 and 25 are not both true
>  9 and 27 are not both true
>  9 and 29 are not both true
>  9 and 31 are not both true
>  9 and 32 are not both true
>  9 and 35 are not both true
>  9 and 36 are not both true
>  11 and 13 are not both true
>  11 and 22 are not both true
>  11 and 23 are not both true
>  11 and 26 are not both true
>  11 and 28 are not both true
>  11 and 34 are not both true
>  12 and 29 are not both true
>  12 and 30 are not both true
>  13 and 20 are not both true
>  13 and 21 are not both true
>  13 and 25 are not both true
>  13 and 27 are not both true
>  13 and 29 are not both true
>  13 and 31 are not both true
>  13 and 32 are not both true
>  13 and 35 are not both true
>  13 and 36 are not both true
>  14 and 24 are not both true
>  19 and 31 are not both true
>  19 and 32 are not both true
>  20 and 22 are not both true
>  20 and 23 are not both true
>  20 and 26 are not both true
>  20 and 28 are not both true
>  20 and 30 are not both true
>  20 and 34 are not both true
>  21 and 22 are not both true
>  21 and 23 are not both true
>  21 and 26 are not both true
>  21 and 28 are not both true
>  21 and 34 are not both true
>  22 and 25 are not both true
>  22 and 27 are not both true
>  22 and 29 are not both true
>  22 and 31 are not both true
>  22 and 32 are not both true
>  22 and 35 are not both true
>  23 and 25 are not both true
>  23 and 27 are not both true
>  23 and 29 are not both true
>  23 and 31 are not both true
>  23 and 32 are not both true
>  23 and 35 are not both true
>  23 and 36 are not both true
>  25 and 26 are not both true
>  25 and 28 are not both true
>  25 and 34 are not both true
>  26 and 27 are not both true
>  26 and 29 are not both true
>  26 and 31 are not both true
>  26 and 32 are not both true
>  26 and 35 are not both true
>  26 and 36 are not both true
>  27 and 28 are not both true
>  27 and 34 are not both true
>  28 and 29 are not both true
>  28 and 31 are not both true
>  28 and 32 are not both true
>  28 and 35 are not both true
>  28 and 36 are not both true
>  29 and 34 are not both true
>  31 and 34 are not both true
>  32 and 34 are not both true
>  34 and 35 are not both true
>  34 and 36 are not both true
>  Of course, it's always possible to have both be false, since all false is a valid solution.

Each of these statements can be proved in a similar way. For example:

> If 1 and 31 are true then
>  statement 11 : 34 or 01 implies not 32
>  statement 40 : 31 or 15 implies 32
>  1 and 31 are not both true

Or, a bit more interesting:

> If 2 and 11 are both true then:
>  statement 27 : 02 or 19 implies 01
>  statement 29 : 21 or 11 implies 27
>  statement 16 : 36 or 27 implies not 34
>  statement 32 : 02 or 28 implies 23
>  statement 31 : 26 or 23 implies 06
>  statement 19 : 06 or 26 implies 34
>  2 and 11 are not both true

Similar arguments can be made for each of the pairs above.

Comment: Right again, Dr. Xorile, and much faster this time.  I figured as much so this time as promised there is a twist ---- there are 2 conclusions to be reached.  You got one of them.  The hint I will give you is that everything you stated is true.

Comment: First a minor point -- The conclusion "34 will be not 32 unless they are both false"  is not strictly true because there is no solution (all statements true) when both 32 and 34 are true.   Speaking in the general sense there are many valid conclusions of this general type involving different variables in groups of 2,3,4 or more.  However what I'm looking for is shorter and simpler involving 2 variables.

Comment: I don't understand your point. But if 32 is true then 34 is false. And if 34 is true then 32 is false. They cannot both be true. However, there are solutions in which 32 and 34 are both false.

Comment: Yes, we are both correct depending on the universe of possible variable  values to start with.  If we consider only good solutions where all statements are true then you are correct.  If we start with all possible variable values where the universe of combinations include outcomes where not all statements are true then I would be correct.  In short I think this is not important and my bringing this up has only slowed down your path to the solution.  I'll stick to directly relevant stuff from now on.

Comment: But all statements are true, right? Do you mean values? I looked at inferences that can be drawn by considering all possible inferences for each statement and checking to see if they were all true.

Comment: Yes, all statements are true.  However, the way I approach these problems is to look at all or many combinations of variables (not statements) and see which combinations allow all statements to be true.  So early on I'm looking at some or many combinations of variables (attributes) that lead to some incorrect statements.  I then throw out that combinaton of variables (attributes).  Again my suggestion is that this is not worth worrying about.

Comment: Yes, it's correct that there are many pairs of variables where "not both true" are sound conclusions.  You deserve credit for listing these.  However the "not both true" condition is the same as "false/false or false/true or true/false".  What I am looking for is a relationship between 2 variables that is more specific or confining than this.  The conclusion that I seek is very specific in that only 2 SPECIFIC variables are involved and the relationship between them is quite specific and confining.

Comment: In other words I'm looking for are the relationships involving the fewest variables.  There are two and Dr. Xorile already found one (15 is always false). The answers given so far are well done and follow what was asked in the problem statement. The fact that what I'm looking for hasn't been found is entirely my fault but done with the purpose of not giving away too many hints. So please tell me if you would like me to say exactly what form of relationship between variables I'm looking for.

Comment: Give me a bit of time

Comment: I'm in no hurry --- just let me know if and when you want to know what type of relationship to look for.

Comment: I find empirically that 11 and 27 are both true or both false. Obviously 11 -> 26 (statement 29), but it doesn't seem to go the other way around. I can't think of a better relationship between 2 variables than this. I mean, there's only FF,FT,TF,TT. All pairs have FF. In my answer, I eliminated a bunch with TT. This plausibly eliminates a pair from being TF (definitely) and from FT (not sure why this would be so other than empirically with a reasonable search time).

Comment: In fact, empirically, I haven't found solutions for 2,6,9,13,15,23,26,28, or 34 being True. For 15 I know I can get to a contradiction. I haven't managed that with the others.

Comment: You can stop now.  You've got it right with 11 and 27 being positively correlated.  Very good.  That's what I was looking for.  Now for the final question which I haven't mentioned

Comment: Because there are 2^36 combinations of variables it's not very quick to test all of them for compliance with all statements.  If you have done this then great.   If not it's possible that there is one combination out there with 11 being opposite value to 27 and would thus disprove our conclusion here.   This also applies to the first conclusion that 15 is always false.  Our conclusion must be stated along with a level of confidence or probability that we are right.  I'm just finishing that now if you want to take a shot at it.

Comment: 15 is definitely always false. Logic for that is in the post. The other one is harder to justify conclusively. Interesting puzzle. A lot of potential.

Comment: I generally agree with you.  However, (and this is perhaps a small point) but the only reason to include 15 in a certainty or confidence level calculation is that only a small subset of problem statements is used when the technique of direct logical chain is used.  In this case it's possible that there exists in the statements not considered a contradiction, inconsistency, or similar when compared with the subset used for the proof.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87122/discussion-between-bob-bixler-and-dr-xorile).